# Eclipse ClassPath variable pointing to Windows Environment variable

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables, classpath

Is there a way to set an eclipse classpath variable to point to a windows environment variable? I tried the normal windows style command line evaluation

> %MY_ENV%

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax is  :

```
${env_var:MY_ENV}
```

But you probably have to declare it in preferences (using the above syntax) :

```
Windws > Preferences > Java > Build Path > ClassPath Variables > New...
```

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. Can you cite a source? Is there some trick that I have to know?